# ASP.NET: Objects in Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have objects in my DataSource i.e

```
.Select(e => new { Foo = new { Bar = "HelloWorld" }, Price = 12345 }
```

how do I reference this using Eval?

```
<%# Eval("Foo.Bar") %>
```

doesn't work? (Eval("Price") does....)

Is there anyway to do <%# Eval(Eval("Foo"),"Bar") %> or something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is in reference to a DataBound control where you're binding to some List or anonymous IQueryable, you should be able to use `Eval("Bar")` since the Foo is already indicated in the bind.

**Edit:**
Looking at your update, if you want to use the `<%# %>` notation, you might be able to get away with it by using `Container.DataItem`.

```
<%#  ((Foo)Container.DataItem)["Bar"] %>
```