# Accessing Data in Objects Using Eval in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, eval

Say I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string x;
}

public class B
{
    public A a;
}
```

I then bind my repeater to a list of class B's. Is there any way using Eval that I can get class A's x data member?

For example, `Eval("A.x")`. I know that won't work, but just curious if there was a convention for doing this.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388009/asp-net-objects-in-eval) post, but I don't believe it actually answers my question.

Comment: Have you tried doing this, but using properties rather than public members?

Comment: Please avoid the `asp` tag... you know, the one with the big "DO NOT USE" message in the help text when you select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not done it using the syntax in the referenced post, but I have done this:

```
((A)Eval("A")).x
```

if I have properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `Eval` in a function that returns the data you're after

```
<%# PullDataFromObject(Eval("B")) %>


Protected A PullDataFromObject(B myObject)
{
    return B.a;
}
```

or something like that .. not compile checked etc